# Motionbuilder to Blender: Still no true FBX support?

Tags: rigging, .fbx, motion-capture

Has anyone found a way to successfully import an FBX file that contains an armature and skin from Motionbuilder to Blender?  I just got royally screwed on a project because zi didn't know there were issues with the FBX format until today.
What's incredibly frustrating is I can import animated FBX files from other sources, but nothing I've created/cleaned up in motionbuilder.